# Showing 1st 25 record or 1st 50 record on Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the codes below:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: setData(),
            pageable: false
        },
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        selectable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 230" },
            { field: "Sex", title: "Sex", width: 50},
            { field: "Ca", title: "C.A." , width: 55},
            { field: "TotalScore", title: "Total Score", width: 100},
            { field: "Rank", title: "Rank", width: 60 }
        ]
    });

    $("#button1").on("click", function() {
       // show 1st 25 records
    });

    $("#button2").on("click", function() {
       // show 1st 50 records
    });
```

---

Now what I want, when the I click a button "button1," it will only show the 1st 25 records or when i click "button2" it will only show the 1st 50 records.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: You want to show on 25 records out of 100 or you want to show 25 records in first page when click on `button1`???

Answer (score 0):

1. create a function named bindGrid:

   ```
   function bindGrid(data) {

   if ($("#grid").data("kendoGrid"))
       $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").destory()

   $("#grid").empty();
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
       dataSource: {
           data: data,
           pageable: false
       },
       scrollable: true,
       sortable: true,
       selectable: true,
       columns: [
       { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 230 },
       { field: "Sex", title: "Sex", width: 50 },
       { field: "Ca", title: "C.A.", width: 55 },
       { field: "TotalScore", title: "Total Score", width: 100 },
       { field: "Rank", title: "Rank", width: 60 }
       ]
   });
   }
   ```
2. store grid data in a global variable and call bindGrid function:

   ```
   var gridData=setData();
   bindGrid(gridData);
   ```
3. Now handle button clicks and rebind grids

   ```
   $("#button1").on("click", function () {
   // show 1st 25 records
   var newDataSource = [];
   $.each(gridData, function (i, item) {
       if (i < 25) {
           newDataSource.push(item);
       }
   });
   //rebind grid
   bindGrid(newDataSource); });

   $("#button2").on("click", function () {
   // show 1st 50 records
   var newDataSource = [];
   $.each(gridData, function (i, item) {
       if (i < 50) {
           newDataSource.push(item);
       }
   });
   //rebind grid
   bindGrid(newDataSource); });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: setData(),
        pageable: false
    },
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    selectable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 230" },
        { field: "Sex", title: "Sex", width: 50},
        { field: "Ca", title: "C.A." , width: 55},
        { field: "TotalScore", title: "Total Score", width: 100},
        { field: "Rank", title: "Rank", width: 60 }
    ]
});

$("#button1").on("click", function() {
   $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize(25);
});

$("#button2").on("click", function() {
   $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize(50);
});
```

Example here: http://dojo.telerik.com/aQID